# Unnecessarily view are added in listView

Tags: android, json, listview, layout

I am using ListView to Display the JSON Data.Within the ListView i have implemented Dynamic LinearLayout to populate as the listitems.I am able to Display the JSON data in the listView as well as within the linearlayout.When the program is exected the view are added unnecessarily.i think the issue is of looping,but dont know exactly.How can this issue be solved?

**Fee**

```
public class Fee extends Fragment /*implements View.OnClickListener   */ {

    LinearLayout receipt1, receipt2, receipt3, receipt4;
    LinearLayout receipt1detail, receipt2detail, receipt3detail, receipt4detail;
    LinearLayout DescriptionAmount;


    TextView statustextView, feedescription, feeamount;
    ListView listViewfees, listviewfeedetail;
    List<StudentFeeInformation> yourData = new ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation>();

    public static final String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/Api/financeApi/getAllFees";
    String Amount;
    String Descriptionlist, status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate;
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    String master_id;

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView textView;
    //  public JSONArray jArray1;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_listview, container, false);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_description_data, null);


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        receipt1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_receipt1_fee);

        //  receipt4 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_receipt4_fee);

        //  receipt1detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt1_fee);
        //  receipt2detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt2_fee);
        //  receipt3detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt3_fee);
        //  receipt4detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt4_fee);

        //   receipt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt2.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt3.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt4.setOnClickListener(this);


        //   receipt1detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //   receipt2detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   receipt3detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   receipt4detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        statustextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_status);
        SessionManagement sessionManagement = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        master_id = sessionManagement.getMasterId();
        listViewfees = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_student_fees);
        // listviewfeedetail = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listtest);

        //  DescriptionAmount = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_linearlayout1);
        // DescriptionAmount.addView(view);


        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_linearlayout1);
        //   v = (LinearLayout)( view.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.student_fees_description_data, null));
        //  linearLayout.addView(view);

        feedescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);
        feeamount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);


        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);


        getUsersListData();


        return view;
    }


    public void getUsersListData() {


        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?id=" + master_id + "&fromDate=" + "&toDate=";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list = new ArrayList<>();


                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                status = jsonObject.getString("Status");
                                DateofReceiptIssued = jsonObject.getString("DateOfReciept").substring(0, 10);
                                ReceiptNumber = jsonObject.getString("RecieptNo");
                                FeeReceivedDate = jsonObject.getString("recivedDate").substring(0, 10);


                                String Description = jsonObject.getString("Description");
                                JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(Description);
                                //  student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate));
                                //
                                //JSONArray jArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Description");
                                StudentFeeInformation sInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate);

                                for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {


                                    JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                    System.out.println("total length" + jArray1.length());
                                    Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("des");
                                    Amount = jsonObjectinner.getString("Amount");
                                    arrayList.add(Descriptionlist);
                                    Log.d("ArrayList", String.valueOf(arrayList));
                                    //  student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(Descriptionlist, Amount));
                                    sInformation.addFeeDescription(Descriptionlist);
                                    sInformation.addAmount(Amount);


                                }

                                System.out.println("total lengthArray" + jArray.length());
                                student_list.add(sInformation);


                            }

                            System.out.println("student_list size:" + student_list.size());
                            CustomFeeListStudentAdapter customFeeListStudentAdapter = new CustomFeeListStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list);
                            listViewfees.setAdapter(customFeeListStudentAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("This is not good");

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.Fee.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // do s.th.
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**CustomFeeListStudentAdapter**

```
public class CustomFeeListStudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LinearLayout reciptViewDynamic;

    Context mContext;
    Fee fee = new Fee();

    ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list;


    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";

    public CustomFeeListStudentAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.student_list = student_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        System.out.println(student_list.size());
        return student_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return student_list.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder viewHolder;


        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fee, parent, false);


            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new Holder();
            viewHolder.student_profile_fee_status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_status);
            viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_ReceiptIssuedDate);
            viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_ReceiptIssuedNumber);
            viewHolder.student_profile_FeeReceivedDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_FeeReceiptDate);
            // viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);
            // viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);

            //added code
            viewHolder.receiptLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recipt_layout);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + postion + " getFeeDescription" + student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription());
        Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + postion + " getAmount" + student_list.get(postion).getAmount());


        viewHolder.student_profile_fee_status.setText(student_list.get(postion).getStatus());
        viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedDate.setText(student_list.get(postion).getReceiptIssuedDate());
        viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedNumber.setText(student_list.get(postion).getReceiptIssuedNumber());
        viewHolder.student_profile_FeeReceivedDate.setText(student_list.get(postion).getFeeReceivedDate());
        //  viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount.setText(student_list.get(postion).getAmount());
        // viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description.setText(student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription());

        // viewHolder.receiptLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
        //added code

        //  Fee fee=new Fee();
        //   JSONArray x=fee.jArray1;

        Log.d(TAG, "@@ wrong information:" + student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription().size());

        viewHolder.receiptLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription().size(); i++) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //   reciptViewDynamic = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bil_info, null);


            reciptViewDynamic = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bil_info, parent, false);
            viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount = (TextView) reciptViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);
            viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description = (TextView) reciptViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);
            viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount.setText(student_list.get(postion).getAmount().get(i));
            viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description.setText(student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription().get(i));
            System.out.print(viewHolder);

            // Log.d(TAG, "@@ wrong information:" + student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription());
            viewHolder.receiptLinearLayout.addView(reciptViewDynamic);


            Log.d(TAG, "@@  massive wrong information:" + student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription().get(i));


        }

        // (reciptViewDynamic).removeView(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView student_profile_fee_status;
        TextView student_profile_ReceiptIssuedDate;
        TextView student_profile_ReceiptIssuedNumber;
        TextView student_profile_FeeReceivedDate;
        TextView student_profile_Fee_Amount;
        TextView student_profile_Fee_Description;
        LinearLayout receiptLinearLayout;
    }


}
```

**json**

```
[
  {
    "MasterID": "E0017",
    "StdID": 95,
    "Status": "U",
    "AmountPaid": 1200,
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "DateOfReciept": "2017-06-01T00:00:00",
    "Description": "[{\"des\":\"Admission\",\"Amount\":1200},{\"des\":\"Due\",\"Amount\":0}]",
    "dueAmount": 0,
    "receivedAmount": 0,
    "RecieptNo": 80,
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson",
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "recivedDate": "2017-06-01T00:00:00",
    "dueDate": "2017-06-29T00:00:00",
    "reciever": "Hari Har Sharma"
  }
]
```

**StudentFeeInformation**

```
public class StudentFeeInformation implements Serializable {
    public String Status;
    public String ReceiptIssuedDate;
    public String ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    public String FeeReceivedDate;
    public String FeeDescription;
    public String Amount;


    public StudentFeeInformation(String status, String ReceiptissuedDate, String ReceiptissuedNumber, String FeereceivedDate) {
        Status = status;
        ReceiptIssuedDate = ReceiptissuedDate;
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = ReceiptissuedNumber;
        FeeReceivedDate = FeereceivedDate;


    }


    public StudentFeeInformation(String feeDescription, String amount) {

        FeeDescription = feeDescription;
        Amount = amount;

    }


    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedDate() {
        return ReceiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedDate(String receiptIssuedDate) {
        ReceiptIssuedDate = receiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedNumber() {
        return ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedNumber(String receiptIssuedNumber) {
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = receiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public String getFeeReceivedDate() {
        return FeeReceivedDate;
    }

    public void setFeeReceivedDate(String feeReceivedDate) {
        FeeReceivedDate = feeReceivedDate;
    }


    public String getFeeDescription() {
        return FeeDescription;
    }

    public void setFeeDescription(String feeDescription) {
        FeeDescription = feeDescription;
    }


    public String getAmount() {
        return Amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        Amount = amount;
    }


}
```

**logcat**

```
   06-08 12:40:21.519 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: MasterID:0095
06-08 12:40:21.519 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Name:Calvin Patterson
06-08 12:40:21.519 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Access:4
06-08 12:40:21.519 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Issued:Thu, 08 Jun 2017 06:55:22 GMT
06-08 12:40:21.519 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Expires:Fri, 09 Jun 2017 06:55:22 GMT
06-08 12:40:21.519 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: user_name_masterID1:0095
06-08 12:40:21.848 28277-28369/com.example.user.mis E/EGL_emulation: tid 28369: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
06-08 12:40:21.849 28277-28369/com.example.user.mis W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa827f920, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
06-08 12:40:21.898 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/Term ID: 6014
06-08 12:40:21.898 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/Term ID: 6015
06-08 12:40:21.899 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/Term ID: 6016
06-08 12:40:21.899 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/Term ID: 6017
06-08 12:40:21.899 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/Term ID: 6018
06-08 12:40:21.899 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/Term ID: 6019
06-08 12:40:21.899 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/All Exam: 6
06-08 12:40:21.960 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: total length2
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/ArrayList: [Admission]
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: total length2
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/ArrayList: [Admission, Due]
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: total lengthArray1
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: student_list size:1
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
06-08 12:40:24.041 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: response is [{"MasterID":"E0017","StdID":95,"Status":"P","AmountPaid":1200.0,"CLASS_ID":2021,"DateOfReciept":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","Description":"[{\"des\":\"Admission\",\"Amount\":1200},{\"des\":\"Due\",\"Amount\":0}]","dueAmount":1200.0,"receivedAmount":0.0,"RecieptNo":83,"NAME":"Calvin Patterson","CLASSNO":"1","recivedDate":"2017-06-08T00:00:00","dueDate":"2017-06-29T00:00:00","reciever":"Hari Har Sharma"}]
06-08 12:40:24.057 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
06-08 12:40:24.057 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
06-08 12:40:24.059 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/HomeTab_adapter: @@ wrong information:2
06-08 12:40:24.062 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
06-08 12:40:24.062 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/HomeTab_adapter: @@ wrong information:2
06-08 12:40:24.423 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
06-08 12:40:24.423 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
06-08 12:40:24.426 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis D/HomeTab_adapter: @@ wrong information:2
06-08 12:40:24.427 28277-28277/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 1
```

**debugged image**
[image]
 where i am doing wrong i am not able to find out.how can this issue be solved?

Comment: What is in `StudentFeeInformation` class ?

Comment: Model Class .updated @Priyankpatel

Comment: @PriyankPatel i have updated the getting image.The inner Layout is displaying more than 1 .I have update JSON Data also

Comment: @PriyankPatel i am not able to find exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `StudentFeeInformation` class according to below.

```
public class StudentFeeInformation implements Serializable {
    public String Status;
    public String ReceiptIssuedDate;
    public String ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    public String FeeReceivedDate;

    // take a ArrayList object for description and amount as it can be multiple 
    public ArrayList<String> FeeDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> Amount = new ArrayList<String>();


    public StudentFeeInformation(String status, String ReceiptissuedDate, String ReceiptissuedNumber, String FeereceivedDate) {
        Status = status;
        ReceiptIssuedDate = ReceiptissuedDate;
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = ReceiptissuedNumber;
        FeeReceivedDate = FeereceivedDate;


    }



    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedDate() {
        return ReceiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedDate(String receiptIssuedDate) {
        ReceiptIssuedDate = receiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedNumber() {
        return ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedNumber(String receiptIssuedNumber) {
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = receiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public String getFeeReceivedDate() {
        return FeeReceivedDate;
    }

    public void setFeeReceivedDate(String feeReceivedDate) {
        FeeReceivedDate = feeReceivedDate;
    }


    public ArrayList<String> getFeeDescription() {
        return FeeDescription;
    }

    public void setFeeDescription(ArrayList<String> feeDescription) {
        FeeDescription = feeDescription;
    }


    public ArrayList<String> getAmount() {
        return Amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(ArrayList<String> amount) {
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public void addFeeDescription(String description) {
        FeeDescription.add(description);
    }

    public void addAmount(String amount) {
        Amount.add(amount);
    }

}
```

Now, in inner `for` loop of `getUsersListData()` method, you are creating new object of `StudentFeeInformation` and adding in list two times.

```
student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate));

 for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {

     JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);
     System.out.println("total length" + jArray1.length());
     Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("des");
     Amount = jsonObjectinner.getString("Amount");
     arrayList.add(Descriptionlist);
     Log.d("ArrayList", String.valueOf(arrayList));
     student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(Descriptionlist, Amount));
}
```

Change above code as below.

```
// create new object of StudentFeeInformation
StudentFeeInformation sInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate));

 for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {

     JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);
     System.out.println("total length" + jArray1.length());
     Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("des");
     Amount = jsonObjectinner.getString("Amount");
     arrayList.add(Descriptionlist);
     Log.d("ArrayList", String.valueOf(arrayList));

     // Add fee Description and amount in same object instead of create new object every time
     sInformation.addFeeDescription(Descriptionlist);
     sInformation.addAmount(Amount)    
}
student_list.add(sInformation);
```

Finally, change code inside `getView()` method of adapter as below.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription().size(); i++) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //   reciptViewDynamic = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bil_info, null);


        reciptViewDynamic = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bil_info, parent, false);
        viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount = (TextView) reciptViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);
        viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description = (TextView) reciptViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);
        viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount.setText(student_list.get(postion).getAmount().get(i));
        viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description.setText(student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription().get(i));

        viewHolder.receiptLinearLayout.addView(reciptViewDynamic);
    }
```

Comment: Completely balnk.not any information are displayed.log shows inner Array is 2 and outer one is 1.logcat is added.please check

Comment: i got confused.Why the one is showing no information

Comment: put some logs and check, is description and amount and other StudentFeeInformation added correctly?

Comment: innerlist information are printed in the LOG.log edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146048/discussion-between-ghimire-and-priyank-patel).

Comment: adding the 
 viewHolder.receiptLinearLayout.removeAllViews();//before entering the for loop

solved my issue